# Magento Installation Failed

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm learning `Magento` but currently I'm stuck with it's basic installation. I have created a db in `Phpmyadmin` called 'magento' and I also put the magento files that I had downloaded in the `htdocs` folder of `xampp`.  I have entered the basic information of my database such as the name and username but when I hit the proceed button to the next part which creating admin account, I got this:

[image: print screen]

I have no idea about whats going on here, so if you know please let me know.

I also tried re entering information but still facing the same problem and I can't even go back to the previous level!

Comment: Do try and post minimal errors as plain-text, not as screenshots. Plus, if you do post a screenshot make an effort to trim off anything irrelevant or potentially embarrassing like those browser tabs and such.

Comment: clear your magento cache and log tables and try again

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps while installing Magento (1.X versions).

1)Check all the required php modules are installed or not (php-gd, php-mcrypt, php-soap etc ..).

2)Create database, user and add privileges to created user to the created DB.

3)Dump magento sample data into the database and continue installation.

Answer (score 0):

In your database table already exists.Just "clear" your db (drop table) and try again.